# newcommand not working in table of contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref

I have defined a newcommand in my .cls file:

```latex
\newcommand\ion[2]{#1$\;${%
\ifx\@currsize\normalsize\small \else
\ifx\@currsize\small\footnotesize \else
\ifx\@currsize\footnotesize\scriptsize \else
\ifx\@currsize\scriptsize\tiny \else
\ifx\@currsize\large\normalsize \else
\ifx\@currsize\Large\large
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\rmfamily\@Roman{#2}}\relax}%
```

However, when I try to use this in a section, subsection, or subsubsection header, it triggers the following error which conflicts with how it is referenced in the TOC:

```latex
Missing { inserted
```

Is there a way to fix this so that the newcommand is correctly referenced in the TOC?  This appears to only happen in section headings, and only when the TOC references a section with the newcommand.

Comment: Try `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.  Also, check out the `relsize` package (it defines `\smaller`, which seems to be what you need).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Unfortunately neither `\DeclareRobustCommand` nor the `relsize` package fixed the problem.

Comment: Please augment your code snippet into a compilable test document, which begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Incidentally, why did you set the `hyperref` tag?